# MySQL 5.6 OS X 10.8: how tell if my.cnf read?

Tags: mysql, my.cnf, mysql-5.6

With `mysqld` running, I expect to see that `/etc/my.cnf` has been used by at least one of the commands

```
ps aux | grep mysql | grep -v grep

mysqladmin variables | grep defaults-file
```

showing the value of `--defaults-file`. But I see no such item. Why not?

I *think* `/etc/my.cnf` is being read, since if I put an erroneous entry in its `[mysqld]` section, e.g., `error = true` then when I try to start `mysqld` it aborts with an `ERROR` message.

I'm using the installation by running `mysql-5.6.10-osx10.7-x86_64.pkg` from `mysql-5.6.10-osx10.7-x86_64.dmg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever mysqld is launched, it has four default locations it attempts to locate and read `my.cnf`

If you run the following:

```
mysqld --help --verbose | head -20 > junk.txt
cat junk.txt
```

You will see this:

```
mysqld  Ver 5.6.10 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))
Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Starts the MySQL database server.

Usage: mysqld [OPTIONS]

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
The following groups are read: mysqld server mysqld-5.6
The following options may be given as the first argument:
--print-defaults        Print the program argument list and exit.
--no-defaults           Don't read default options from any option file,
                        except for login file.
--defaults-file=#       Only read default options from the given file #.
```

Note the line that says:

```
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

These are the four files read (if they exist).

The above displays come from a Linux Box. So, please run

```
mysqld --help --verbose | head -20 > junk.txt
cat junk.txt
```

and see what locations are echoed.

## UPDATE 2013-03-17 22:35 EDT

The reason you cannot see the [**`--defaults-file`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-safe.html#option_mysqld_safe_defaults-file) option is not visible is simple: Since one or more of the default `my.cnf` files are present, [**`mysqld_safe`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-safe.html) does not show it on the command line.

Please note the following:

- [**`mysqld`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld.html) uses the four defaults
- You cannot set [**`--defaults-file`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-safe.html#option_mysqld_safe_defaults-file) for mysqld. That's the job of **`mysqld_safe`**
- **`mysqld_safe`** needs it explicitly specified in order for it to be visible in the OS

Running `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;` will not show any defaults file

```
mysql> show global variables like '%def%';
+------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name          | Value  |
+------------------------+--------+
| default_storage_engine | InnoDB |
| default_week_format    | 0      |
| table_definition_cache | 400    |
+------------------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: On my Mac I see locations `/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf ` in that output, the 3 options you show, and one more: `--defaults-extra-file=# Read this file after the global files are read`. But this still doesn't answer my question: should I be seeing the value of `defaults-file` when I make the queries I originally showed?

Comment: OK, thanks, that 2013-03-17 update does clarify the situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On OS X, here is a simple method to check whether your file is read.

1. Run: `sudo fs_usage | grep my.cnf`

   <sup>This will report any filesystem activity in real-time related to that file.</sup>
2. In another Terminal, restart your MySQL/MariaDB server, e.g.

   ```
    brew services restart mysql # or: mariadb
   ```
3. On terminal with `fs_usage`, the proper location should be shown, e.g.

   ```
    15:52:22  access            /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.1.14/my.cnf                                         0.000002   sh
   ```